# How do I find the path to my php source distribution?

Tags: php

I am a .NET developer trying to build up my skills with PHP and open-source-style development. I am trying to get an hang of Pear and install my first PECL extension. The [instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.intro.php) say that they

> assume /your/phpsrcdir/ is the path to the PHP source distribution

I installed PHP via a bitnami  MAMP stack.

How can I tell which folder in PHP contrains the source distribution?

Answer (score 2):

Add a page php_info.php and put this in it:

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

// Show just the module information.
// phpinfo(8) yields identical results.
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

?>
```

Now look, for example, at `extension_dir`, and your php is normally installed somewhere above that. For example if it is `/hsphere/shared/php55/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212` then check to see if your php is located at `/hsphere/shared/php55`.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

If that's not enough, here are a bunch more commands that may work depending on what you're looking for and what OS you're on:

```
php-config --php-binary
php-config --extension-dir
php-config --include-dir

php -i | grep php
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"

find / -name php.ini
```

One of those should find what you're looking for!

Comment: This is not helpful. That produces a huge page with a ton of information. I still don't know where to find the php source dir.

Comment: Thanks, that is more descriptive. For me I didn't find them there but at least you gave me a more specific place to check.

Comment: Added more ways to find it, do any of those bottom ones work for you?